# How to display softInput : EditText in TabHost with erratic behavior

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, android-tabhost

i'm having some problems with autofocus in a tabhost . I need to display softinput and focus in the editText when i open that tab (with that edittext) , better explained with the next picture :

[image]

In one tab i have that layout . But when i open it , the editText doesn't gain focus. I have done it badly opening program the editText when the tab shows , but it behavior is erratic and  it only runs second or third times it does .

What i want is to do it automatically , like often it does android on editText . I put code now :

**tab_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/AbsoluteLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingBottom="6dip"
        android:weightSum="4.0">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/search_field" 
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:maxHeight="45dip"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="3.1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:lines="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint_text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/edit_text_hint_search"
            android:background="@drawable/et_search_field"
            android:textColor="@color/edit_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/edit_text_highlight" />
        <ImageButton android:text="Search" android:src="@drawable/ic_search_normal" android:id="@+id/search_button"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/search_field"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/search_field"
            android:background="@drawable/button_generic"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
            android:padding="10dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then i have the activity into an activity group , but i think it musn't be a problem for autofocus , basically this is what i do with that layout:

```
public class SearchListActivity extends ListActivity implements OnScrollListener
{
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ...
    View v = View.inflate(this, R.layout.tab_header, null); 
        getListView().addHeaderView(v);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Thanks for reading , all help will be gratefully read.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in the OnResume override:

```
EditText ET=(EditText) findViewById (R.id.search_field);
ET.requestfocus();
ET.SetText("Your soft input");
```

Comment: onResume fires , but soft input doesn't run with that , neither with   ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(search_field,0);